# PHP 7 and install that in Centos 7 VMs

Tags: linux, php

i want download PHP 7 and install that in "Centos 7" Virtual Machine
note ,that Virtual Machine not have a internet

thanks ,

Comment: How do you want to download if you haven't an internet access? That doesn't make sense!

Comment: download from another pc have cantos also , after that transfer those file into Centos and install it @Toto